BottomNavigationView is empty unless EdgeToEdge does not exist
Changed the height of the BottomNavigationView to 56dp, as it is the "standard" size. Unless I make it larger, or remove EdgeToEdge the icon is not shown at all, unless I use BottomPadding="0dp", in which case a small slice is shown.
java:
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) ->
        {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        bottomNavMenu = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_menu);
        bottomNavMenu.setOnItemSelectedListener(item ->
        {
            int itemId = item.getItemId();
            if (itemId == R.id.Gmaps)
            {
                replaceFragment(new GmapsFragment());
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
    }
}

xml:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:itemIconSize="24dp"
        app:itemPaddingBottom="8dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
</LinearLayout>


I tried working with chatgpt and gemini to find an answer after not finding anything myself, and after roughly an 2-3 hours gave up, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Can you add menu/bottom_nav_menu.xml ?

Sure, sorry for not adding it earlier.
`

<item
    android:visible="true"
    android:id="@+id/Gmaps"
    android:title="Gmaps"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_map_24"
    />

 `
Sorry it ended up a bit messy, I'm new to stackoverflow
Same issue. Guess, by applying the window insets as bottom padding, there is not much height left for the actual BottomNavigationView in 3-button-navigation. But I also did not find a solution to this, sorry.

Here, they recommend to set layout_height="wrap_content", not mentioning how to achieve the 56dp height: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/493

That's the best info I found: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/4247#issuecomment-2259240962
In 1.13 alphas, you can use the minHeight attribute together with layout_height="wrap_content".
